# Receiver receive long sms but showing it multiple times

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am developing a SMS Application in which i am receiving Sms. Now the first problem was that when long sms received then the receiver splits it in different parts. i.e. it always show the last sms and not the full sms. But then i searched alot and figured out that i need to append the full sms so that all parts are joined up. But now another problem occured.When sms received I am showing it in listview. And after this append solution when long sms received then listview showing multiple items. i.e. if sms is long lets say it is counted as 3 Sms then the listview is showing first sms in listview then it is also saving 2nd part of the sms and finally it is saving the full sms. What to do to just display full sms in listview?
Here is my code for receiving sms:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
  String msg_from;
  String msgBody = "";
  if (bundle != null) {
    try {
      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

         msgBody += msgs[i].getMessageBody();

        msg_from = Utilities.extractNumbers(msg_from);
        Long dateLong = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
        String msgDate = dateLong.toString();
```

As u see in this line :

```
msgBody += msgs[i].getMessageBody();
```

I am appending all the part of sms in one. but i am sure the problem is still here Please Help

When message receives I am checking if it is from contact. If not then it is going to this method:

```
screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
```

Here is what this method is doing, it is saving it in database and then i am showing data from db to listview.

```
public void screenMessage(Context context, String msg_from, String msgSender,
  String msgBody, String msgDate) {
DBsms smsdb = new DBsms(context);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsdb.getWritableDatabase();


String query_insertSMS = "insert into " + "sms" + "(" + "contactnumber" + "," + "contactname" + "," + "message"
    + "," + "date" + ") values (\"" + msg_from.toString() + "\", \"" + msgSender + "\",\"" + msgBody
    + "\",\"" + msgDate + "\")";

dbw.execSQL(query_insertSMS);
smsdb.close();
dbw.close();
abortBroadcast();
```

}

and one thing more I also check after putting

```
log.e("key",msgBody);
```

but is is also showing 3 count SMS to 3 times so basically i think the problem is still with receiver which is getting long message but displaying it multiple times

Comment: Your problem would seem to be elsewhere. How are you getting the messages in your `Activity`? And how are you handing them to the `ListView`'s`Adapter`?

Comment: let me edit my code for you Sir

Comment: Are you calling your `screenMessage()` method inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, is it the issue?

Comment: Yep. You wanna do that after the loop.

Comment: Ok let me check this

Comment: How stupid I am. It works like a charm Thankyou sir :)